# Theorem about n=1 wave equation in Evans

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Evans, PDE edition 2 on p68 we have a Theorem  that tells us some properties about the solution to the wave equation for $n=1$. It reads:

Assume $g \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, $h\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, and define u by

$$ u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left( g(x+ct)+g(x-ct) \right) + 
\frac{1}{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} h(y)dy$$

with $c>0$ to solve the one dimentional wave equation given by

$$
   f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}=0 & \text{in } \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)\\
       u(x,0)=g(x) & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times \{t=0 \} \\
       u_{t}(x,0) = h(x) & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times \{t=0\}
     \end{array}
   \right. .
$$
Then

(1) $u \in C^2( \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty)) $

(2) $u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0$ in $\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$

(3) $\lim_{(x,t) \rightarrow (x_0 , 0^{+})}u(x,t) = g(x_0)$ and 
$\lim_{(x,t) \rightarrow (x_0 , 0^{+})}u_{t}(x,t) = h(x_0)$

This proof was left to say "done by direct calculation", and I did that for (1) and (2), but with the style that Evans has been proving the (3)'s in previous similiar theorems for the heat equation and laplace's equation, I'm unsure of what to do here after fiddling around with it for a while. Can someone help? (1) and (2) are EXTREMELY direct, but I'm unsure of how to prove (3) with use of a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use $\delta-\epsilon$?. Just exploit the continuity of $g$ (and $h$) as well as the representation formula for $u$. This yields the first identity in $(3)$ directly. Differentiating $u$ w.r.t. $t$ one obtains the second identity with a similar reasoning

Comment: You know what, you're totally right. That was silly.

Comment: I only have Evans' first edition at hand. I assume that $c$ is positive, right? Then there seems to be a sign error in the formula provided above. It should be $g(x+ct) + g(x-ct)$, shouldn't it? Then everything should really be clear :)

Comment: yes you're right. $c>0$, and I saw that mistake in my notes right before i saw your message. thanks!

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: since your comment answered the question, maybe you can convert that to an answer so DaveNine can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Willie Wong's request:

It is not necessary to use the $\delta-\varepsilon$ formalism. It suffices to exploit the represenation formula of $u$, the continuity of $g$ and that 
the integral containing $h$ is continuous to infer the first identity in $(3)$. Differentiating $u$ w.r.t. to $t$ and using again the properties of $g$ and $h$ shows the second identity in $(3)$.